# An incremental storage / database

Tags: database, version-control

I am looking for a method to store only the incremental values of documents in a storage. It can be a database or a file system but the main requirements are:

- Fast (adding documents, saving new revisions and retrieving all should be handled as fast as possible)
- Efficient (it should use the least amount of storage while keeping it fast enough)
- Able to handle a lot of files (billions of files/documents)

At first I was using SVN and now my best choice seems to be [Git](https://git-scm.com/). It has all the thing I want. However, it has a few issues.

1. I have to have a copy of the last version of each document in the repository. Which equals to a lot of files sitting at the storage folder.
2. It seems like it's kind of overkill to use a full version control just to use its storage capability. I'm not sure if this has any disadvantages or not though.

I think the ideal solution would be a database which has something like a version control or basically git's core functionality at its core.

Is there such solution? Is it possible for just 1 developer to somehow easily create such tool without months/years of research and effort?

What would you recommend and why?

Comment: What kind of files do you plan to store?  If binary files (e.g. images, MS Office documents), then get ready for a shocker if you use Git: your repo will quickly bloat and become unusable, because Git doesn't diff binaries well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen They're mostly web documents i.e. HTML, JS, CSS AND images. So they're both text and binary.

Comment: For source code stuff, e.g. HTML, JS, XML and other plain text source files, Git might be a suitable option, but not for images, unless the images are very small (e.g. tiny icons) and you only have a handful of them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What would you recommend for images?

Comment: Well, if you're looking for a VCS type of solution, then something like Perforce or maybe SVN could be an option.  If you just need to _store_ images, without any need for versioning, then Amazon's S3 could be an option.  It really depends on what your needs are.

Comment: You're looking for a Document Management System. Unfortunately, requests for product recommendations/shopping lists are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @alroc the thing is that if for instance I'm looking for a text editor, there are a lot of options to choose from and the "best" is subjective. However, in my case I really haven't found any system to do what I need. If you know any, please tell me.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Git does meet your requirement. The database or incremental storage just as the `.git` folder for a git repo.

Remote repo is the place which only store the delta changes ([checksum](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Committing%20Your%20Changes)) for different version. And it’s bare repo, that means there is no working directory (no documents of last version exist). So the **you can treat remote repo as database**.

#### 1. Create a remote repo:

You can create remote repo locally or hosted on github, bitbuket etc. For remote repo hosted on github or bitbucket, you just need to sign up and create a repository, then clone a working copy for it. So I just list create a remote repo locally here:

```
# In an empty folder, such as D:\repo
git init --bare
```

Now you have an empty remote repo in `D:\repo`.

#### 2. Making changes for the remote repo/database:

Working in the git repo, you need a working copy (local repo). So you can clone a local repo from [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and make/commit changes. When you want to store the changes in remote repo (database), just push changes to remote.

```
# In another directory, such as D:\local
git clone D:/repo
cd repo
# Add/create files you want to store in git repo (D:\local\repo)
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

Now what you make changes will be stored in the remote repo.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was quite busy. I know about the bare repo. However, since the changes are often, I'm not sure how efficient it would be to clone the repo every time I want to make a change. If I wanted to keep both the bare repo and the working directory, it would be 2 versions of the documents and that means a lot of disk space. Imagine being able to somehow add the changes directly to the bare repo. That's what I need. Something like: `add this file to the repo` or `save changes to that file`

Comment: The bare repo works as database, and you should making changes on local repo with working directory. After finishing changes and ready to record it to bare repo. You needn't clone the bare repo every time, it just need to pull changes from the bare repo (if others also work for it), and push your local changes to the bare repo.

Comment: Ummm I'm not sure you read the whole comment but as I said, if I keep the working directory it means that I keep 2 copies of the same repo and that means a lot of disk space.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's does the way for git works: remote repo and local repo. You you can also refer https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server for further understanding about remote repo means. And for local repo, you can delete it and it won't effect for your database (remote repo).

Comment: Correct. But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't force me to use 2 repo. I'm looking for something that does the same thing but directly. It could be a database or maybe if it's not a huge task, I could make it myself. I'm looking for help to achieve this

Comment: Ok, for this reason, your expected solution should't limited between git and svn. I removed these tags.

Comment: I added the tags because I think what I'm looking for is related to both of them. Didn't mean to limit the solution to either one.